# How to get all table and view connection in oracle

Tags: oracle

How to extract all views and tables from a Oracle database including the column connections? I think in MySQL I could use KEY_COLUMN_USAGE which contains this information, is there anything equivalent in Oracle including the views?

Example:

```
Table1 |      Table2 |        Table3
ID1    |>>>>> ID1    |>>>>>>  ID2
Name   |      Date   |         Code
Adress |             |
```

I would like to get the information that:

```
Table1 is connected with Table2 via ID1>ID1 
Table2 is connected with Table3 via ID1>ID2
```

Comment: What do you mean by "column connections"?

Comment: I mean the relationship between two views, how the columns are connected.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand.  If you have two tables, you can declare a referential integrity constraint (a foreign key) between the two to show a relationship.  You can't declare a foreign key between one view and another.  You could look for views that have columns with the same name but there is no guarantee that those would actually define a relationship.

Answer (score 1):

What would "column connections" be?

---

I guess you need `USER_TABLES`, `USER_VIEWS` and `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`. Former 2 views returns information about tables and views, while the latter contains info about columns in those tables/views.

You'd join them as

```
select ...
from user_tables t join user_tab_columns on c.table_name = t.table_name
```

The same goes for `USER_VIEWS` (as `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` contains columns from both tables and views).

---

If you want to check **all** tables and views you have access to, you'd use `ALL_TABLES`, `ALL_VIEWS` and `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`, but this time - in join condition - include the **OWNER** column, e.g.

```
select ... 
from all_tables t join all_tab_columns c on c.owner = t.owner 
                                        and c.table_name = t.table_name
```

---

Finally, if you have DBA access, then use `DBA_` views (query would look the same as for `ALL_` views).

---

**[EDIT]** After all, it seems you're looking for foreign key constraints. In that case, query `USER_CONSTRAINTS` and `USER_CONS_COLUMNS`.

Here's an example: to illustrate it, I'll create a master-detail tables pair:

```
SQL> create table master (id_master number constraint pk_mas primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table detail (id_detail number constraint pk_det primary key,
  2                       id_master number constraint fk_det_mas references master (id_master));

Table created.
```

Query you'd execute is:

```
SQL> select fk.table_name ||' is connected with ' || pk.table_name ||' via ' ||
  2         fc.column_name ||' > ' || pc.column_name as result
  3  from user_constraints fk join user_constraints pk on pk.constraint_name = fk.r_constraint_name
  4  join user_cons_columns fc on fc.constraint_name = fk.constraint_name
  5  join user_cons_columns pc on pc.constraint_name = pk.constraint_name;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMP is connected with DEPT via DEPTNO > DEPTNO
DETAIL is connected with MASTER via ID_MASTER > ID_MASTER

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks, I can extract all the views and table information but I don't know how to extract the connections. I added an example in the description.

Comment: OK; I edited the answer and added some more code. Have a look, please.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this when saying you want to expose table *and view* "connections", which is traditionally referred to as relationships.

```
create table EMP (ID number primary key);

create or replace view FOOLS_ERRAND as
select ID EMP_ID from EMP;
```

Do you *really* want to try to write code that can say FOOLS_ERRAND is related to EMP? If you do, then be prepared to execute SQL statement parsing code that can create and scan a parse tree for the entire select statement syntax. Even if you obtain an execution plan for `select * from FOOLS_ERRAND`, there's no guarantee that appearances of EMP or its unique index scan in the row source operations guarantee the view is related to the table (like a table is related to another). About the best you could say is that the view makes reference to the table.

I recommend you stick with retrieving a table's declared constraints either from [ALL_CONSTRAINTS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/ALL_CONSTRAINTS.html) and [ALL_CONS_COLUMNS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/ALL_CONS_COLUMNS.html) or its USER and DBA variants.